# script to turn the light off and on [ C# , Unity 3d ]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made this little script that should turn the light of a point light off and on ... unfortunately only the off button works, after which it doesn't turn on again .... maybe there is some error in the script?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class TurnLight : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject light;


private bool on = true ;


void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) {
       

    if (other.tag == "Player" && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E) && !on)
    {
       
        light.SetActive(true);
        on = true;
    }
    else if (other.tag == "Player" && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E) && on)
        {
        light.SetActive(false);
        on = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd you put the script on the light object it will be deactivated when you do SetActive(false)

Comment: it seems to work but partially ... sometimes it turns on and off without problems other times it is turned off and I turn it on, it turns on for a thousandth of a second and then it turns off by itself ... other times it is on and I turn it off, turns off for a thousandth of a second and then turns on again ... how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please Check this link to understand **OnTriggerStay** Function

[On Trigger Stay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay.html)

Also Please check those to differentiate between
[Get Key](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) and
[Get Key Down](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html)

the problem is calling of **OnTriggerStay** happens continuously and you are using **GetKey** functions which will return true all times if the player pressed.
So when you use **GetKey**  this will cause Single press on E will be redden multiple times.

Here is my solution

```
 public GameObject light; 

bool isPlayerStandingNear = false; 
private void Update()
{
    if(isPlayerStandingNear)
    {
        //Debug.Log("isPlayerStandingNear");
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            Debug.Log("Light State : "+ light.active);

            light.SetActive(!light.active);
        }
    }
}

void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        isPlayerStandingNear = true;
    } 
}
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        isPlayerStandingNear = false;
    }
}
```